# Как сделать смену темы?

Tags: android, android-sdk, themes, android-themes

как сделать смену темы во всё android приложении?
Вот код, который у меня получился:
Settings.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner choose_theme;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;



    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        String[] themes = {
                "Сера буро малиновая тема",
                "Фиолетовая тема",
                "Зелёная тема",
                "Оранжевая тема",
                "Жёлтая тема",
                "Красная тема",
                "Синия тема",
                "Чёрная тема",
                "Светлая тема",
        };




        choose_theme = findViewById(R.id.theme);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, themes);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        choose_theme.setAdapter(adapter);

        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String theme = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


                //Set new Theme

                if (theme.equals("Красная тема")){
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red);

                }else if(theme.equals("Жёлтая тема")){
//                    yellow theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow);
                }else if(theme.equals("Синия тема")){
//                    blue theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Blue);
                }else if (theme.equals("Чёрная тема")){
//                    black theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Black);
                }else if(theme.equals("Светлая тема")){
//                    white theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                }else if (theme.equals("Зелёная тема")){
//                    green theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Green);
                }else if (theme.equals("Фиолетовая тема")){
//                    purple theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Purple);
                }else if (theme.equals("Сера буро малиновая тема")){
//                    gray brown crimson theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_GR);
                }else if (theme.equals("Оранжевая тема")){
//                    orange theme
                    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Orange);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };
        choose_theme.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {



        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если неинтересно эту всю простыню читать, то решение в самом низу отмечено :)**

Я могу предложить сохранить данные про тему в [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences), и дальше тащить данные где вам нужно. Для начала я бы советовал немного изменить ваш код по выбору темы в слушателе виджета:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };
```

выше представлен пустой слушатель. Можно немного более лаконично все сделать:

```
switch (parent.getItemAtPosition(position)) {
           case  "Красная тема":
               setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red)
               break;
           ...
           default:
               // здесь можно установить дефолтную тему приложения например
               break;
       }
```

теперь по поводу того как сетить тему во всех активностях/фрагментах. Вам нужно сохранить в память устройства переменную которая позволит идентифицировать вашу тему и выбрать соответствующий стиль. Для этого мы при выборе пункта списка будет записывать данные о выборе. [Вот есть туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) на тему хранения данных. В методе `onCreate()` вашей активности настроек мы инициализируем переменную:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

и при выборе темы записываем данные:

```
mSettings.edit().putString("theme_col", parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).apply();
```

дальше в любом месте активности вы можете получить выбранную и сохраненную ранее переменную и засетить тему:

```
switch (mSettings.getString("theme_col", "")) {
               case  "Красная тема":
                   setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Red)
                   break;
               ...
               default:
                   // здесь можно установить дефолтную тему приложения например
                   break;
           }
```

с учетом того что кусок кода для выбора темы будет повторяться как минимум в двух местах я бы советовал его вынести в отдельный метод отдельного класса и просто передавать в него стринг темы, но вот вопрос в том что он будет возвращать. Если в отдельном классе сетить тему, то нужно передавать так же контекст, а в противном случае вынос в отдельный класс может быть не совсем целесообразным :)

### UPDATE

Я что-то протупил немного, когда сказал что класс ничего не сможет вернуть того что нам нужно. Стиль это Integer, поэтому и метод должен его возвращать. Делаем класс-синглтон:

```
public class Singleton  {
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }
}
```

добавляем метод:

```
public class Singleton  {
    ...


    Integer processTheme(String name){
        ...
    }
}
```

сам метод будет делать то же что и вы делали только немного иначе. Но перед этим объявим два массива: массив с русскими названиями тем и их идентификаторами:

```
String[] themes = {
            "Сера буро малиновая тема",
            "Фиолетовая тема",
            "Зелёная тема",
            "Оранжевая тема",
            "Жёлтая тема",
            "Красная тема",
            "Синия тема",
            "Чёрная тема",
            "Светлая тема",
    };

    Integer[] themesIDs = {
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_MaterialComponents_Title_Panel_CenterStacked,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents_Light
    };
```

я стили брал вообще левые, но суть я думаю будет ясна. Дальше вот сам метод:

```
Integer processTheme(String name){
   return themesIDs[Arrays.asList(TYPES).indexOf(name)];
}
```

целый класс выглядит так:

```
public class Singleton  {
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

    String[] themes = {
            "Сера буро малиновая тема",
            "Фиолетовая тема",
            "Зелёная тема",
            "Оранжевая тема",
            "Жёлтая тема",
            "Красная тема",
            "Синия тема",
            "Чёрная тема",
            "Светлая тема",
    };

    Integer[] themesIDs = {
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_MaterialComponents_Title_Panel_CenterStacked,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents_Light
    };



    Integer processTheme(String name){
        return themesIDs[Arrays.asList(TYPES).indexOf(name)];
    }
}
```

дальше при выборе темы из списка на экране настроек вы вызываете данный метод:

```
String theme = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
mSettings.edit().putString("theme_col", theme).apply();
setTheme(Singleton.getInstance().processTheme(theme));
```

весь слушатель будет выглядеть так:

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              String theme = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
              mSettings.edit().putString("theme_col", theme).apply();
              setTheme(Singleton.getInstance().processTheme(theme));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };
```

дальше как я уже говорил выше, вы можете получить выбранную переменную в любом месте и засетить тему:

```
setTheme(Singleton.getInstance().processTheme(mSettings.getString("theme_col", "")));
```

**Итоговое решение**

Но и этот метод не совсем идеальный. По факту вам нужно просто сохранять в память позицию элемента в массиве чтобы ее потом передать. В таком случае вы сохраняете в память Integer позиции:

```
mSettings.edit().putInt("pos",position).apply().apply();
```

строчка выше должна находится в теле слушателя выбора пункта списка. Метод в синглтоне и сам синглтон немного изменится и будет таким:

```
public class Singleton  {
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        public static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }


    Integer[] themesIDs = {
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_MaterialComponents_Title_Panel_CenterStacked,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents,
            R.style.Platform_MaterialComponents_Light
    };



    Integer processTheme(Integer pos){
        return themesIDs[pos];
    }
}
```

и дальше соответственно для возврата идентификатора темы делаем в слушателе выбора темы так:

```
setTheme(Singleton.getInstance().processTheme(position));
```

а в других классах делаем так:

```
setTheme(Singleton.getInstance().processTheme(mSettings.getInt("pos", 0)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно конечно долго и нудно разрабатывать свои темы и проч., но по мне (IMHO безусловно) - это какой то антипаттерн.

Можно сделать все гораздо проще. Грубо говоря есть 3 темы:

1. Системная (дефолтная тема установленная в системе)
2. Ночная (она же night)
3. Дневная (она же light)

Выбор той или иной темы делается просто:

```
 //системная тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
 //light тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
 //ночная тема
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

Если вы сильно не увлекались созданием ресурсов типа `res/values/themes.xml` и т.д., то это все работает обычно из коробки. Если увлекались, то придется возможно попотеть прописывая `themes.xml`

Comment: У меня это не работает. Всегда включена системная тема